# Append List Element Multiple Times based off Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Here's what I have so far

```
var count_element = $('div.wp-playlist-item > li').length;
totalcount = 10 - count_element;
if ( totalcount > 1 ) {
       $('div.wp-playlist-item').append('<li class="wp-playlist-caption"><div title="" data-original-title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="0:00" data-placement="left" class="next-songs"><span class="wp-playlist-item-title">Blank</span></div></li>');
}
```

Basically I am trying to make it so that `div.wp-playlist-item` always has 10 list elements.

So, unless `totalcount` = 0 (10 - 10), append this list element.

In my current test environment, `totalcount` is equal to 8, so we want to fire our append command 8 times.

My current code works properly only to fire the proper append once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count_element = $('div.wp-playlist-item > li').length;
totalcount = 10 - count_element;
if ( totalcount > 1 ) {
  for (var i=0; i< totalcount; i++) {
     $('div.wp-playlist-item').append('<li class="wp-playlist-caption"><div title="" data-original-title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="0:00" data-placement="left" class="next-songs"><span class="wp-playlist-item-title">Blank</span></div></li>');
   }
 }
```

Demo https://jsbin.com/qanoput/edit?html,js,output

Try this once loop and append.

Comment: Wow super simple.  Thought it'd be more complicated than that. Thank you, you were the first.  Also +1 for demo.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, a `for` loop should do what you need. Also, I believe you want `totalCount` to be greater than 0, not 1:

```
 if ( totalcount > 0 ) {

       var i = 0,
           appendedElement = '';

       for(; i < totalCount; i++) {
           appendedElement += '<li class="wp-playlist-caption"><div title="" data-original-title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="0:00" data-placement="left" class="next-songs"><span class="wp-playlist-item-title">Blank</span></div></li>';
       }

   $('div.wp-playlist-item').append(appendedElement);
}
```

Note the advantage of this approach is that you concatenate in the `for` loop, which should be fast, and the `append()` is executed only once instead of multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

the if statement only runs once as it is not inside or being called from a loop.
If you want to run the code an X number of times add that code inside a function and create a loop that calls that function

```
var totalCount = 10 - count_element;

for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
  myFunction()
};

function myfunction(){
 //your code here
}
```